# How can I set the keyboard focus to the content of a ContentPresenter when it changes?

Tags: wpf

I have a ContentControl in my view which is databound to the CurrentItem property of my viewmodel.  The objects that are exposed via CurrentItem each has its own DataTemplate.

When the CurrentItem property changes, the appropriate DataTemplate for that item is displayed, as it should be.  However, I cannot find out a way to set the keyboard focus to the content of the DataTemplate.

Even if I manually set the keyboard focus to the DataTemplate, if the CurrentItem property changes (and a new Template is instantiated) the focus is lost (FocusManager.GetFocussedElement returns null).

How can I set the keyboard focus to the content of the ContentPresenter when it changes?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use the [LayoutUpdated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.layoutupdated.aspx) event on either your ContentControl or the ContentPresenter. This should fire anytime the Content/ContentTemplate/etc changes.

Alternatively, you could derive a class from ContentControl then override the [OnContentChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.oncontentchanged.aspx), [OnContentTemplateChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.oncontenttemplatechanged.aspx), etc methods. Then you'd need to search down the visual tree and set the focus. You may need to use the Dispatcher to delay the focus setting code.